# Decision to make a NAS server

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, nas, raspberry-pi

I have a 1 TB seagate external HDD with four partitions on it. Many a times my Windows 7 does not allow to me to "safely remove hardware" - I googled on solving this in the first place, only to find out that this a Microsoft flaw and has no definite answer / solution.
Now that because of transportation and unsafe ejects all my four partitions are asking me to format the respective logical drives
I have a recovery software and I'm confident that I'd recover it.
To avoid this happening in future, I'm thinking to move to a NAS server. I found that using Raspberry PI - I could build a low power NAS server.

My questions:

1. Is it correct to select a NAS server for this purpose of not moving this HDD from one place to another?
2. I'd like my storage to be accessible over internet. Is it possible? [Is my NAS accessible from the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/769613/is-my-nas-accessible-from-the-internet]). This link says it is extremely unlikely to make a NAS available over the network. Is it still true?

Any other means of not physically removing and connecting the HDD and not relocating it - will extend the life time of the HDD and keep it safe. That is the main intent of this question.

Comment: You can use windows sharing to make your Windows 7 box a NAS for the local network rather than using a pi. To make the storage available externally over the network you can use something such as HFS (HTTP File Server) and port forwarding on your public facing router.

Comment: Please do not close this question. _It is not opinion based._ I'm asking for suggestion whether or not an NAS will help me keep my HDD in one place in order for it to be safe

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use a Raspberry pi as a nas, and making it available on the Internet is easy, you just need a service like NoIP amd some basic knowledge of Linux. You should need a samba server for lan sharing (samba is windows sharing protocol) and an ftp server for remote access. But take in mind that over the Internet thr the maximum download speed is equal to your home network upload speed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'm planning to get a Raspberry PI for this reason. I will edit the question further before accepting the answer. Thanks @Fabiusp98

Comment: I'm going to put instructions in a couple of days when I finish mine.